# Meteor synchronous function call on the client

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm using Meteor and React, and I'm trying return data from a third party javascript function

The function takes a callback and returns a value. The function takes a few seconds to resolve

At the moment the callback returns an undefined value but after a few seconds a console log will display the correct data

My current code is as follows

```
// ON THE CLIENT
// callback function that returns a deviceId
const callback = function( data ) {

    // this callback fires with the correct data after a couple of seconds
    console.log("Callback ", data);

    return data;
};

// async function that calls third party function with callback
async function getDeviceId() {
    const res = await captureDeviceId(callback);
    return await res;
}

let response = getDeviceId().then( function(value) { 
    return value; 
});

console.log("res", response);
```

The response returns a promise but does not resolve

```
Return {[[PromiseStatus]]: "pending", [[PromiseValue]]: undefined}
```

How can I wait for the functions response before returning the value?
I've tried Meteor wrapAsync, async-await and Promises without success.

Any help would be appreciated

Cheers,

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Trying to get data synchronously would make it easier for your code, but you should get used to the idea of asynchronicity, and write your code to suit. It's no harder once you get used to it, and it makes sense that you don't want to lock up the web page while you wait several seconds for a remote service to respond.

Comment: Thanks for your response Mikkel. Unfortunately I need the return value before I can move onto the next task in the code. This is the last part of in process and I cannot make the last call until I have this value.

Answer (score 0):

*getDeviceId* returns here a promise (even if you do a return inside the .then callback). If you want to ge the value, do it like below:

```
var response;
getDeviceId().then( function(value) { 
    response =  value;
});
```

Comment: Thanks Faly, This now returns response as undefined